# How to get image from google images in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-image-search

I would like to show only the 1st image from Google Images via Swift 2 on my app. I was thinking about using Custom Search API, but I'm not sure if I found the right source to show this 1st image.
Any tutorials?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Custom Search API is probably the best method (the only one that I know that is allowed). You need to obtain an API key from the Google Developers Console for a search engine. 
Then use this guide: [Using REST to invoke the API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest#making_a_request).

Just be sure to include this parameter `searchType="image"` in the request if you are grabbing image search results. You can specify how many results you want from your search.

Here is a tutorial on [REST API calls and parsing JSON with Swift](https://devdactic.com/rest-api-parse-json-swift/). From the request you receive an array in which you will be looking at the items and they will have a `link` property which is the image URL. Here is a [full list of response properties](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list#response).